Reason for bookcase face frame stiles wider than side thickness
In the following image the vertical beaded/scalloped face frame stiles are wider than the thickness of the sides of the bookcase. If a book was all the way to the side, then the stile would prevent you from reading the title on the spine.
Many traditional English/European bookcases seem to be like this.
Is there a functional reason for this or is it about aesthetics and proportion? Has it been written about anywhere?


I'd also be interested in any scholarly discussion of these proportions. In the meantime, you can go back to the classics and see where it started: https://www.thisiscarpentry.com/2018/02/02/rules-for-proportion/

@AloysiusDefenestrate - Great article. Thanks!

The word many is key here, not least because in this case it may not represent the majority as it might be assumed to mean usually (and I strongly suspect it doesn't represent a majority). Without checking, I think this is 100% an aesthetic or decorative choice with no functional purpose, well, other than as a surface to sport the linenfold decoration/fluting! In short, this is a highly ornamented but largely not actively functional design; bookcases intended to be used for book storage AND retrieval simply would not have this sort of obstacle built in (or at least nowhere to this degree).

If you look at contemporary bookcases, quite often there are no decorative fronts at all.  The units are given structural and lateral support by their rear and sides.  On the other hand, these decorative pieces sure look good!
